# Missing stickers for 71374: Nintendo Gaming Console LEGO set

Tags: stickers, replacement-parts

How do I get a replacement sticker sheet for [this product](https://brickset.com/sets/71374-1/Nintendo-Entertainment-System)? The one I received came with no stickers.

Comment: Contact them. The year is 2020.

Comment: @mindstormsboi. Great suggestion, but please be gentle with new posters. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can contact [LEGO customer service](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/) by email, phone and chat about missing parts or sticker sheets.

For third-party sellers, try [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=71374stk01&idColor=0#T=C&C=0).

Comment: Do you mean *third* party sellers?